# Calling multiple functions from single onClick in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have created a VBScript function that allows users to install a network printer by clicking a button. This works great, but there is no feedback after clicking the button. I'm trying to add an alert after the button is clicked, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Here is the functioning onClick function for installing a printer:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
   function AddP(pName)
       Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
       WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
   end function
</script>

<td><a href="#" language="vbscript" onclick="AddP('\\PrinterName')"><input name="Button1" type="button" value="Add"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the user some indication something is happening while the printer is being added you could change the button state.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
   function AddP(pName)
       Dim allButton1s
       Set allButton1s = document.getElementsByName("Button1")
       allButton1s(0).value = "Please wait..."
       Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
       WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
       MsgBox "Printer Added"
       allButton1s(0).value = "Add"
   end function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: Add a colon to your declaration which acts as a statement separator. This will allow you to call an additional function.

`<a href="#" language="vbscript" onclick="AddP('\\PrinterName': msgbox 'Printer added')">`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line after your `WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection` line

```
MsgBox "Printer Added"
```